# Programs stopped starting after an upgrade and downgrade from Windows 10

Tags: windows

I downgraded to Windows 8 from Windows 10. However some of my programs stopped starting. When I press the icon they do not start at all. I searched google and I could not find anything. Does anyone have an idea?

Specific program that I can say is: AVG PC Tune UP- paid and legal.
When I click the ICON the program does NOT START.
The program does not specifically support Windows 10.
Reinstalling the program does NOT solve the problem.

When I ran sfc /scannow I had errors that could not be fixed.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the applications that don't work?

Comment: Yes I did , it did not work.  I can give a specific application: AVG PC Tune Up

Comment: Does this program have specific support for Windows 10?  I don't use programs by AVG, nor any programs that are similar to that program, I consider any program like `PC TuneUp` to be malware (and honestly any program from AVG to be malware).

Comment: Programs that "tune up" the registry are snake oil.  Your clarification on the reason you use it doesn't answer my question.  Does the program specifically support Windows 10?

Comment: It does not specifically support Windows 10, but after rolling back it still does not work. I clarified so I can make a point that it's useful.

Comment: Please edit your question to include all new relevant information.